# How to specify a fixed job name for jobs submitted by qsub

Tags: qsub

I use -N option to specify the name for the job when submitting through qsub. The qsub, however, adds some numeric string after thejob name as described in the man page:
          By default the file name for standard  output  has  the
          form  job_name.ojob_id and job_name.ojob_id.task_id for
          array job tasks (see -t option below).

Therefore, whenever I submit  a new job with same job name, a new suffix .ojob_id is added to the job name and a new output file is created.

What I trying to achieve is to have same output file each time a job is submitted through qsub. How can I do that? I have to run a job several time and I want the output from a run to overwrite the output file generated in the previous run. How can I achieve that?
See the example below:

First time command is given to run script `hello_world` to output in `log_hello_world`:

```
qsub -cwd  -N log_hello_world    hello_world.sh
```

It creates two output files:

```
log_hello_world.e7584345
log_hello_world.o7584345
```

Second time the same command is given: It creates two more output files

```
log_hello_world.e7584366
log_hello_world.o7584366
```

What can I do to get the output in just one file `log_hello_world`.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this issue by using options -o and -e to save the log and the error files respectively. With these options, the log and the errors from the job are written into same file every time from this command.

```
qsub -cwd  -N job_hello_world  -o log.hello_world -e error.hello_world  hello_world.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append a file with a fixed name. This is done in the code which you run. You create a file in your directory, and then append it with the new results each time you run your code. So in your code (not in the qsub line), explicitly add a line of code which asks the results to be written to a file in your directory, in Mathematica this would be

```
str = OpenAppend["/home/my_name/Scratch/results.dat"];
Write[str,results];
Close[str];
```

Where *results* is a variable which contains the results of your computation. Then just run the job using `qsub -N log_hello_world hello_world.sh`. This will write the results to the same file every time you run the job without changing the name of the file.
(If you're looking to write both -o and -e files to the same file, you can just add `-j y` to the qsub after having specified the file path for the error file)